# Hide Server name NGINX on windows Environment

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, nginx-status

I am using NGINX. I don't want to disclose my server Identity. For that, I research many sites and found to hide the version of NGINX on Windows Environment.

```
Command on windows:server_tokens off;
```

Now How to hide or modify the Name of server i.e

```
Server: nginx
```

to

```
Server: "Customname"
```

I found somewhere info that there is NGINX-EXTRA module which can do this stuff. But I don't know how to get and what is the procedure. If anyone has the knowledge of this or something which can solve my requirement then please let me know. Any help is Really Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

---

1.you can modify the source file 'src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c', and then rebuild nginx.

```
static u_char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: nginx" CRLF;
static u_char ngx_http_server_full_string[] = "Server: " NGINX_VER CRLF;
static u_char ngx_http_server_build_string[] = "Server: " NGINX_VER_BUILD CRLF;
```

2.you can write a nginx http module to modify http header info

Comment: NGINX_VER is define in 'src/core/nginx.h'

Comment: I am using on windows not on unix. Is this Work on Windows. I think not